# Chromecast API - cuts out JPEG image edges

Tags: chromecast

I'm broadcasting JPEG images using a simple HTML5 Chromecast API and I notice the images are shown with all edges cut.
I do the same on a Monitor with HDMI input and images are shown perfectly fine.

Is there a best resolution/size should be used when using? Just FYI I have no issue broadcasting videos!

Thanks for your suggestions.

Amir

Comment: try scaling diff img sizes around 1080p . try margin or padding around the img.

Comment: Scaling didn't work, I went to 1000 and still the same issue. Adding padding was my next step but hoping I don't have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a small portions that are not visible? If so, you may look at the settings on your TV for overscan and turn that off and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks again Ali, My tv didn't have a overscan option but by playing with its picture setting I found a mode called Wide PC mode that shows the whole image.